# How to get system environment variables using boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, platform-independent

I work on windows and MacOS, I would like to get environment variables.
How to get system environment variables using boost library?

Are there equivalent to `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` from **.Net** ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no need for Boost. Use `std::getenv` from `<cstdlib>`, which is a standard C++ function.

Comment: It seems there are no portable system environment variables in boost. FileSystem has a portable file names, but environment  variables are not portable: Win7 has HOMEPATH and *NIX has a HOME, same for USERNAME and USER.

Comment: @Arman: portable homedir finding is relatively useless, since Windows and Unix have very different conventions as to where user-specific data must be stored.

Comment: Yes I agree, but to store program general options is useful to have some convention: on linux usually user programs are storing $HOME/.myset or windows probably %userprofile%/.myset or something similar. Therefore better to have portable functions.

Comment: @Arman: you could define a function `get_home` that returns `$HOME` is that's set, `$HOMEPATH` otherwise.

Comment: The problem is that std::getenv isn't thread-safe, and there doesn't seem to be a std::dupenv.

Comment: @traal: that's only a problem if you call `setenv` from another thread, right? And having threads communicate through the process environment doesn't sound like a great idea to me...

Comment: std::getenv is neither reentrant nor thread-safe.  Not a good choice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286934/warning-c4996-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-compared-to-gcc-on-pos

Comment: C++ 11 - unlike earlier standard revisions - does guarantee the std::getenv() is thread-safe, as long as no modifications are done to the environment concurrently - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv .

Comment: As for storing user-options in a portable way, you should probably use a higher-level library that provides such functionality through platform-agnostic abstractions, such as [tag:wxwidgets].

Answer (score 4):

You probably want a plain `c` (and `++`) [`getenv()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getenv/) function, it needs not to be boosted.