# "getenv... function ... may be unsafe" - really?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings, crt, getenv, c-standard-library

I'm using MSVC to compile some C code which uses standard-library functions, such as `getenv()`, `sprintf` and others, with `/W3` set for warnings. I'm told by MSVC that:

> 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Questions:

- Why would this be unsafe, theoretically - as opposed to its use on other platforms?
- Is it unsafe on Windows in practice?
- Assuming I'm not writing security-oriented code - should I disable this warning or actually start aliasing a bunch of standard library functions?

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286934

Comment: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ENV01-C.+Do+not+make+assumptions+about+the+size+of+an+environment+variable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getenv()` is potentially unsafe in that subsequent calls to that same function may invalidate earlier returned pointers. As a result, usage such as

```
char *a = getenv("A");
char *b = getenv("B");
/* do stuff with both a and b */
```

may break, because there's no guarantee `a` is still usable at that point.

[`getenv_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv) - available in the C standard library since C11 - avoids this by immediately copying the value into a caller-supplied buffer, where the caller has full control over the buffer's lifetime. `dupenv_s()` avoids this by making the caller responsible for managing the lifetime of the allocated buffer.

However, the signature for `getenv_s` is somewhat controvertial, and the function may even be *removed* from the C standard at some point... see [this report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1969.htm).

Comment: According co [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) this is not the case for C++11 and later. Old results may be invalidated by calls to POSIX setenv(), unsetenv(), and putenv() but not by other calls to getenv.

Comment: @AndrewPenkrat: What about C11?

Comment: @einpoklum for C11 it's still an issue and getenv_s was introduced there. This question, however, has both C and C++ tags while current answers only cover the C language.

Comment: So  what is the exact way in which you can rewrite getenv("environment_variable") in terms of _dupenv_s?

Answer (score 1):

`getenv` suffers like much of the classic C Standard Library by not bounding the string buffer length. This is where security bugs like buffer overrun often originate from.

If you look at `getenv_s` you'll see it provides an explicit bound on the length of the returned string. It's recommended for all coding by the [Security Development Lifecycle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sdl/) best practice, which is why Visual C++ emits deprecation warnings for the less secure versions.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) and [this blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972816.aspx)

> There was an effort by Microsoft to get the C/C++ ISO Standard Library to include the Secure CRT [here](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1031.pdf), some of which was approved for C11 Annex K as noted [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv). That also means that `getenv_s` should be part of the C++17 Standard Library by reference. That said, Annex K is officially considered optional for conformance. The `_s` bounds-checking versions of these functions are also still a subject of some [debate](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1969.htm) in the C/C++ community.

Comment: But the interface of `getenv()` does not have the caller provide the buffer. So where's the risk? As long as the library itself does not introduce a bug, i.e. does not overrun anything, and makes sure to return a `'\0'`-terminated-string - the caller is perfectly safe. Or am I missing something? Of course returning the length of the environment string is nicer, but that's not about security.

Comment: If the function is used in a mutlithreaded environment, then the buffer could be modified while someone is reading from it. It is also not re-entrant, meaning that if, while reading the buffer, you make a function call that also eventually calls getenv(), then the value could change unexpectedly.