# C++17 what new with : error C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead

Tags: c++, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

i try to do a simple task and get environment variable both in Linux and windows
all docs point to use : std::getenv
but when i run the compilation in windows 10 using visual studio 2019 I'm getting :

```
error C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

This is the function :

```
std::string Utils::getEnvVar(std::string const& key)
{
    char* val = std::getenv(key.c_str());
    return val == NULL ? std::string("") : std::string(val);
}
```

i found only this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568707/getenv-function-may-be-unsafe-really) , which i don't understand what is the solution for cross-platform solution.

Comment: If you search more generally for the error message, without specifying `getenv` explicitly, then you should be getting a lot more hits about the "problem" and possible solutions. As a quick workaround, the error message itself contains a hint about how to disable the warning.

Comment: MS VS2019 doesn't like some old C calls, accessing raw pointers and buffers and such. They have a point: it is possible to use it wrong and create a backdoor in your program, making it possible to be exploited. So you'll have to convince VS that you really want to use it.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c#comment64207522_631717) comment on "why"

Comment: On Windows, use [`GetEnvironmentVariableW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentvariablew). Create a 3rd function that wraps this on Windows and `getenv` on Linux into a common interface.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler message says it all:

> error C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

The warnings is MSVC specific. It warns about usage of an unsafe C standard function.

If you only need to compile on MSVC, then

> Consider using _dupenv_s instead.

If you need cross platform compatibility, then

> To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Which is a define, so just `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Another solution would be to disable the warning (`#pragma warning(disable: 4996)`).

See also [Remove secure warnings (_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS) from projects by default in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis).

Comment: But what is the actual problem with std::getenv?

Comment: I found another thread about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: @Bernd I don't know what MS thinks is the problem with `getenv`. They don't mention it on the [docs for getenv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv) or [getenv_s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-s-wgetenv-s). Reading [security functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt) maybe they wanted better parameter validation and enhanced error reporting. Or they want to prevent that code erronously writes to `*getenv(...)` which returns `char*` and not `const char*`?

Comment: @WernerHenze you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c#comment64207522_631717) comment for "why".

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dupenv-s-wdupenv-s?view=msvc-160) "_dupenv_s uses the copy of the environment pointed to by the global variable _environ to access the environment." So the alternative suggested by the warning does the same as `getenv`.

Comment: @Werner the alternative is `GetEnvironmentVariableW` from Win32.